# How can I collect client-side information on errors in my PHP application?

Tags: php, javascript, error-reporting, feedback

I'm putting together an enterprise application using PHP and Yii. I want an easy way for the users to report a problem or bug if one occurs however I'm having a difficult time deciding the best way to capture/record the state of the system to help duplicate the problem.

I was looking for an extension or library that integrates everything but that might not exist. Otherwise I need to look for a way to serialize the DOM for later evaluation or some other method like that.

So the user can click the "Report Bug" button which captures the state of the site and brings up a pop-up box with a "what happened?" text box the user can fill in.

What are my options to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home) (formerly known as Hoptoad) and its [php notifier](https://github.com/rich/php-hoptoad-notifier). By default they don't save full DOM code, but I think you can extend the notifier to do that.

To allow users to trigger reports you can use ajax plus a custom exception.

They have free plans and the setup is pretty easy to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the HTML source for the current page you can use this Javascript snippet:

```
var htmlSource = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
```

Another piece of information you might want to save is of course the current URL. You can send all this to the server using [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), e.g.

```
$.post("<?php echo CController::createUrl(...); ?>",
       {
           url: document.location.href,
           html: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML,
       });
```

I don't think you can do more than that without some kind of server-side helper you can call to. What function exactly do you need this bug-reporting feature to fulfill?